# Excel, MID, SEARCH Error

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I have two strings, i want to extract the number in the middle "2200" i am using the formula

```
=VALUE(MID(C3,SEARCH("_",C3)+11,4))
```

C3 is where the string is. this formula working on "string 2" and give me the value i am looking for "2200" but doesn't work for "String 1" i get #VALUE!.  if i change the formula

```
=VALUE(MID(C3,SEARCH("_",C3)+10,4))
```

it works for "String 1" but doesn't work for "String 2"  How can i have same formula work in both situations?

String 1: ABC_1A1B_33C_2200_4AB_ABC4_4800

String 2: ABC_10A1B_33C_2200_4AB_ABC4_4800

thx,

Answer (score 3):

This should work as long as the example `2200` is always 4 digits long:

```
=LEFT(REPLACE(D7,1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(D7,"_","@",3)),""),4)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value you wish to extract is always in the fourth position, then you can try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"_",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),4,1)
```

where `seq_99` is a Named Formula that refers to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

`seq_99` will return an array:  `{1,99,198,297,...,25146}`

Answer (score 1):

This does not care as to the length, only that it is the forth block:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ", 999)),3*999,999))
```

[image]

---

Note

The above returns a text string that looks like a number.  If a number is what is wanted then replace the `TRIM` with `--`

```
=--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ", 999)),3*999,999)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on the static position of the number being between the third and fourth underscore character.

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "_", REPT(" ", LEN(A2)), 4), "_", REPT(" ", LEN(A2)), 3), LEN(A2), LEN(A2)))
```

[image]

Note the **double-unary** (aka *double-minus* or `--`) that converts text-that-looks-like-a-number to a true number.